# Detect if a user liked my fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, detect

EDIT:

Finally after a long search, I found a solution to this:

heres my code:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <fb:like href="http://developers.facebook.com" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>

        <div id="fb-root"></div>

        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
        <script>
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
                //alert('like '+href);
                document.getElementById('download').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href, widget) {
                //alert('dislike '+href);
                document.getElementById('download').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
            });
        </script>
        <div id="download">Download</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works as I wanted, but on page load by default the Download is shown, how do I detect on page load whether the user liked my page or not?

---

OLD QUESTION
I am having a website where I have some files for users for download, and have a like button next to it. I just want that download button to be visible only if the current user liked my page.

I am new to FB open graph and JS SDK, I tried following code(pasted in my website) :

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    oauth      : true,
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    FB.api('me', function(user) {
        if (user) {
          var image = document.getElementById('image');
          image.src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
          var name = document.getElementById('name');
          name.innerHTML = user.name
        }
     });
  } else {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app or
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
     FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
         FB.api('me', function(user) {
            if (user) {
              var image = document.getElementById('image');
              image.src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
              var name = document.getElementById('name');
              name.innerHTML = user.name
            }
         });
       } else {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
       }
     });
  }
 });
};

(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
```

Even though I am logged in FB and using same browser, it always returns me with following error(firebug debug log)

code:2500
message : "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

I dont know much about FB API, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am also looking for same thing, would be great if someone would help us in this :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an edit of your code that should work:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'XXXXXXXXX',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        FB.api('me', function(user) {
            if (user) {
              var image = document.getElementById('image');
              image.src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
              var name = document.getElementById('name');
              name.innerHTML = user.name
            }
         });
      } else {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app or
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
         FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
             FB.api('me', function(user) {
                if (user) {
                  var image = document.getElementById('image');
                  image.src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
                  var name = document.getElementById('name');
                  name.innerHTML = user.name
                }
             });
           } else {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
           }
         });
      }
     });
    };

    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
```

To explain a bit, what I added was a function which checks whether a user has authorized your app yet [(FB.getLoginStatus)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) and within the success handler of that function, I've added your API call. Within the else of this function, I've added a call to [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) which will prompt un-authorized users to auth your app. If they successfully do this, your API call is made, if they chose not to, I've just left in the example console.log call, but you could replace that with anything you wanted.

Now, in order to track whether a user has liked your page or not, you need to make use of the [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) function by tracking the 'edge.create' event.

Comment: I tried your code but when its not working, I have edited my code, just check it'

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'not working' - what errors? Also, you are replacing the XXXXXX bit with your actual App ID, right?

Comment: Yaa I am inserting actual app ID, when I debugged, its not going in FB.getLoginStatus function, so not able to track an exact error.